# Creating a .dll out of existing code

Tags: c++, dll

This is a newbie request. I'm looking for materials on .dll creation. Specifially, i want to create a .dll out of a simple 3D engine i've made to learn about the process. I need information on dynamic link libraries that go deeper than the wikipedia page, how are they created, what's necessary, how to create different .dll files for "debug" and "release", how to create a PDB file for it and how to create a header file that'll allow for easy usage of the library from a, f.e., C++ program. Material with strong theoretical side (not as much, "how to create a dynamic link library in visual studio") would be great.

Please share good materials on the subject, all i can find is some information here and there and it doesn't paint the picture for me.

Comment: This question is way too broad for this site unfortunately. Hope someone can point you towards a tutorial.

Comment: Is this on Windows or another OS? Sounds like Windows if you're talking about DLLs but best to be sure as there are differences between different OS's, so you might want to tag your question as such

Comment: If you can not buy a good book on the subject, then MSDN is the best source available - see "About Dynamic-Link Libraries" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681914(v=VS.85).aspx) and here "Creating Reusable Code (C++)" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384835)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading between the lines, I think you really want to know about libraries in general rather than dll's specifically. A **library** is simply a handy package of object (compiled) code, along with some information about how to call into it. In C++, this usually takes the form of a .h file.

With **static libraries** (.lib), the linker pulls in the code it needs in exactly the same way as it does with all the rest of your classes. A normal class will get compiled to object code (MyClass.obj), and when they're all done the linker sticks them all together and wires up any inter-object calls with the appropriate addresses. It's the identical process with .lib library files. You end up with a big ball of executable code which includes both your classes, and the library functions within it.

With a **dynamic library** (.dll), the only difference is that the linking (wiring) happens at runtime instead of at compile time, and the library object code remains in a separate ball - the dll file. When you compile your exe, all calls that use functions in the library are mapped to a stub function. When Windows loads the dll for you, it will stick the dll code into the same memory area as your process, and wire up the stub functions to the real functions that are now available.

The only other difference is that a dll must expose a function that Windows can call when it loads or unloads the dll, in case the dll wants to do any initial setting up / clearing down. This is traditionally called DllMain().

If you want to learn about libraries, I would concentrate on creating a static .lib first before worrying about dll's. This is where most of the work is. Once you have a lib it is child's play to turn it into a dll.

The main thing you need to think about when creating a library is how you are going to expose your **API** (Application Programming Interface). This is just which functions/classes you are going to expose to the people using your library. You don't have to expose them all, but you do have to decide WHAT to expose. Are you just going to expose some C style functions, or are you going to expose entire objects? This is the real challenge when designing a library. You should try and make your API as easy to use, and obvious as possible if people (and you!) are going to find your library useful.

As for pdb files, differently named release/debug modules, and creating .h files. These are identical to when doing so in an exe.

Comment: As for the relation between a DLL and a PDB, you can have a look at this URL (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37456/How-To-Inspect-the-Content-of-a-Program-Database-P)

Comment: Note that you cannot export certain things with a DLL. For example templated objects, structs with inline members, and even classes in general - though there are kludgy workarounds. This is why COM was invented. Point being, don't make a DLL unless you can really justify all the headache you will introduce.

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a new DLL project, using VS wizard.

2) Add your existing source files to it.

3) Put into *.def file (which should have been created by the wizard) the names of the functions that you want to export from your DLL, as [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Basically, that's it. Debug and release configurations are automatically created by the wizard, but if you want the 2 variants to be named differently, you can change their output names: go to Project Properities -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Target name.